# Django FloatField in ModelForm with 2 precision point

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a FloatField in one of my model. I Add/Edit it using ModelForms. What I need is that,
when I edit, the Float value stored in FloatField to be rendered with exactly 2 precision points.

i.e. if my stored value is `1000.0 or 1000.123`, I want the input field of form to show initial value of `1000.00 or 1000.12`.

Any suggestion on approach will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: If you must use a float field, instead of a decimal field, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739030/restrict-django-floatfield-to-2-decimal-places/46081058#46081058

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know your use case, but using [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) will solve your issue

from the docs:
For example, to store numbers up to 999 with a resolution of 2 decimal places, you'd use:

```
models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```